# Can't install previously installed apps from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, installation

My Samsung Galaxy S2(I-9100) was upgraded to 2.3.6 by the technician at a Samsung Service Station. This resulted in a wiped-off of all the apps that I had installed along with some other data(like contacts,sms etc).

I had to go through the entire procedure of registering your phone with my gmail account.

I cannot install some of the apps that I had previously installed (from the web store) because I cannot choose the device and I get the message "Your device already has this app installed".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: error1]

[image]

Comment: Did you try installing from your device directly instead from the web interface of Play Store? I vaguely remember having a similar issue previously on my phone (HTC Desire).

Comment: @MartinTapankov I hardly use the Play Store on my device because I have a 2g connection and it takes a hell lot of time to load. I tried installing from my device and it works. But I prefer using the web store instead.

Comment: I see your point, I also frequently install apps from the web interface. My point was to try and install the same app from there to see whether it works at all, it might be a synchronization issue with your Google account after factory reset.

Comment: If you don't mind spending, I'd recommend [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) over MiLocker. I can bet.. its the best in Play Store..

Comment: The issue is I cant install some apps and MILocker is one of them. I did try WidgetLocker and i prefer MILocker over that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the uninstall process wasn't registered at Google Play Store.

Without the uninstall process registered, Google Play Store still reports the app as installed on the device that's associated with your Google account.

To overcome this, you need to manually trigger the uninstall from the Google Play Store, within the "MY ANDROID APPS" list:

[image: Access Google Play Store User Apps List]

---

## Step by Step

I have a couple of apps that I've uninstalled from my device and the uninstall process wasn't registered at Google Play Store. I'll use one as a guide:

1. Access "MY ANDROID APPS" list, search for the desired app and click the recycle bin icon to trigger the uninstall:

   > [image: Click the uninstall icon]
2. After confirming, the app will get marked as "removed":

   > [image: Application marked as removed]
3. Now you can access the application at Google Play Store, and install it like you mentioned that you prefer to do:

   > [image: Install the application]

Comment: Is that MY ANDROID APPS section new? It does exactly what I was looking for about a month ago and never found!

Comment: @GAThrawn I would guess 2 months :)

Comment: @GAThrawn Did a search just now and bloggers started talking about this at the end of June.

Comment: I don't have the recycle bin icon.

Comment: The uninstall option has been removed from Play Store... This is no longer relevant. Apparently giving up privacy for Google to see your apps is pointless. Cannot install anything because: "It's already installed"... Hopefully Google will fix this.. don't hold your breath

Answer (score 2):

Error message still appearing

If you've signed in to your device's Google Play Store app, downloaded an item, and your device doesn't appear on the Google Play website, you can try clearing your app's data by following these steps:

1. Open your device's main **Settings** menu.
2. Select **Apps** or **Application manager** (this may be different depending on your device).
3. Select **Google Play Store** from your list of apps.
4. Touch **Clear data**.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play seems to have changed in the last few years and I wasn't able to find an uninstall feature on the web. It seems like the best workaround here is to just install from Google Play on the device itself.